# How to work on my personal ideas during the weekend?

Tags: project, startup

I'm working full time 5 days a week, mostly between 10 and 14 hours a day.
In the end of the day I'm very tired and just wanna take a shower, hang out and go to sleep.

I have a lot of ideas that I want to implement and someday sell maybe through an online software business.

I have my weekends free. However, when I get to the weekend I can't even imagine myself turn on the computer.

But I really want to make my ideas happen, and I can't leave my job right now to devote myself only to my ideas.

What do you say? Do you find some method helpful? Do you use some technique?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you need to reduce your hours so you don't burn out!

Comment: This question is applicable to many jobs, not programming only.

Comment: @Oded - Yes but the answer is scoped to the programmers.  The answer for other professions would be different.  Some of the core problems the OP faces are off topic.  How to complete your personal programming while working as a programmer is programmer specific.

Comment: If you have a colleague, and your colleague is also working an average of 12 hours a day, that's 60 hours a week each, or 120 all together.  You're two developers doing the work of three.  What are you doing this for?  Why are you depriving that third developer of a job?

Comment: I'm doing it because we're a startup with a very tight deadline (we're behind even before we started). Maybe they should hire another programmer!

Answer (score 1):

If you NEED your job like most people do, then the only other option is working outside those hours.

First off, why is your job consistently making you work 10-14 hour days. That is not normal.

Fix that, either by limiting those hours, or finding a new job (not necessarily easy of course in the current economic climate) and you suddenly have whole lot of time to play with.

Comment: I do not know that it is not "Normal" but I agree with the sentiment.  It is not healthy and really not productive over the long term.

Comment: @Chad - I'm sure there are many places that push employees to do this like the OP's, but they are NOT the norm surely?? Maybe some industries, like games or start ups? I don't mind the odd time for a deadline, or I've messed up, but working more than 7.5 hours/day for me is simply not normal. Certainly not across the whole indsutry.

Comment: I think it is pervasive enough that I would not call it abnormal.  And 8 hours a day is pretty standard in the US, 9-10 pretty common, probably more common than 8 hour days.

Comment: @Chad - 7.5 is standard here in UK. 10-14 just wouldn't happen here as norm in most industries. We also get more vacation than you ;-)

Comment: yes you do... now go to India and China and look at what over 1/4 of the worlds population is expected.. and paid.  I agree that it is not good... It is however far to common and sadly normal.

Comment: @Chad - indeed, that is very sad, and for way less pay too.

Comment: This might be an interesting article for that topic: http://www.salon.com/2012/03/14/bring_back_the_40_hour_work_week/

Comment: @user17822- thanks for that link, fascinating article!

Answer (score 1):

Run it like your project manager does.

- Scope and define your project
- Document your requirements
- break it into workable chunks
- Set goals for when you will complete each.
- Work to meet your goals adjusting as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think it comes down to "Just do it". Nike has it right. If you are passionate about those side projects you just dredge through it. I know I have a hard time as well. I'm in a similar situation as you. I have several side projects that I'd love to work on but after a week of programming it's tough.

What I do is reserve several hours on Sunday for the given project. I will dedicate myself to that for 2 weeks. If on the 3rd week I don't feel inspired I take it off. After that off week I'm back to my dedication of 2 consecutive Sundays.

It's hard to think about it in such a way but you have to almost consider it a job. You "HAVE" to do it or you will get fired...never complete it anyway...

Answer (score 0):

In my case I try to keep up with my ideas by having them in a server, that I try to update fairly regular.

In the past I used the [wikipedia](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) But I had the problem of how to trace back what I'm doing with the code, then after trying [collabtive](http://collabtive.o-dyn.de/) and some others I end up with [redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) (so far so good, I can track the code and targets)

The only "problem" is that you may have to sacrifice your lunchtime/cofeetime/whatevernotcomputertime you have left to access to your own server and keep up with the latest ideas you had. Also have a computer close to you, and if no computer, then a blocknote.

Good luck, and don't burn out!